# Validar mi input tipo text no acepte numeros ni signos ni nada solo texto?

Tags: javascript, validación

Como hago para que mi input text no admita números ni símbolos solo letras de acuerdo a mi estructura de validación en mi archivo JS este archivo tiene como nombre usuario.js que valida cada campo de mi formulario, en este archivo obtengo lo que venga de cada input y hago las validaciones que estan a continuación pero no se como hacer lo que nombre anteriormente

```
function validar() {
var nombre, apellido, identificacion, nacimiento, ciudad, correo, telefono, usuario, contrasena, rol, expresion, valContra;
nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
identificacion = document.getElementById('identificacion').value;
nacimiento = document.getElementById('nacimiento').value;
ciudad = document.getElementById('ciudad').value;
correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value;
contrasena = document.getElementById('contrasena').value;
rol = document.getElementById('rol').value;

expresion = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/;
valContra =  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$/;


if (nombre === "" || apellido === "" || identificacion === "" || nacimiento === "" || ciudad === "" || correo === "" || telefono === "" || usuario === "" || contrasena === "" || rol === "") {
    alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
    return false;
}
else if (nombre.length > 30) {
    alert("El nombre es muy largo");
    return false;
}
else if (apellido.length > 30) {
    alert("El apellido es muy largo");
    return false;
}
else if (identificacion.length > 12) {
    alert("La identificacion es muy largo");
    return false;
}

else if (correo.length > 50) {
    alert("El correo es muy largo");
    return false;
}
else if (telefono.length > 10) {
    alert("El telefono contiene 10 digitos");
    return false;
}
else if (usuario.length > 30) {
    alert("El usuario superan los 30 caracteres");
    return false;
}
else if(!contrasena.match(valContra)){
    alert("La contraseña debe tener mas de 6 caracteres y debe contener al menos un número y una mayúscula");
    return false;
}

else if (isNaN(telefono)) {
    alert("El teléfono ingresado no es un número");
    return false;
}
else if (!expresion.test(correo)) {
    alert("El correo no es valido");
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar la siguiente expresión regular para letras en español, .test() te sirve para evaluar si ese string cumple con la expresión regular, te devolverá true o false según corresponda

```
let myText = "palabravalida";
/^([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ])+$/i.test(myText)
```

en tu codigo seria mas o menos asi:

```
} else if (nombre.length > 30 ) {
    alert("el nombre es muy largo");
    return false;

} else if (!/^([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ])+$/i.test(nombre) ) {
    alert("el nombre solo puede contener letras");
    return false;

} else if (apellido.length > 30 ) {
    alert("El apellido es muy largo");
    return false;

} else if (!/^([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ])+$/i.test(apellido ) ) {
    alert("el apellido solo puede contener letras");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Amigo pero como seria dentro de mi codigo para las variables nombre y apellido

Comment: ahi modifique la respuesta

Comment: No funciono amigo

Comment: Que puede estar mal?

Comment: abre la consola de chrome y te indicara el error

Comment: lo que pasa es que como no llega al ultimo if lo que hace es de una vez mandar el formulario al controlador
y o que veo es que en el corchete cuadrado de comienzo esta en verde

Comment: lo modifique denuevo, disculpa es que el editor de codigo me borro el formato

Comment: Ahora si funciono, pero el otro problema es que no admite espacios

Comment: [a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s\ ] este admite espacios